# Is there any way to use the clipboard in Monogame?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I know these things are trivial in windows forms and other GUI based libraries, but is there a way I can copy a string to my clipboard in Monogame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works just fine as long as you have a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`, which shouldn't be a problem if you are using "standard" MonoGame for Windows.  This gets more interesting if you are trying to be cross platform compatible, or are using one of the unofficial MonoGame ports with a WPF back-end.

`System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText("This is some text");`

Comment: What are these "unofficial MonoGame ports with a WPF back-end." you talk about?

Comment: It allows you to use WPF as the MonoGame host instead of Winforms. https://github.com/MarcStan/MonoGame.Framework.WpfInterop

Comment: Ah man, that's cool. I'm already using my own hand rolled WPF interop with MonoGame but I might learn something from that. Thanks.